# Android collapsing toolbar with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am attempting to use the collapsing toolbar in conjunction with a `RecyclerView`, most examples of collapsing toolbar that I can find are usually with a static scrollview and the few I have found with a `RecyclerView` don't work, has anyone been able to make this work? I will include my xml code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: which version of `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7` do you use?

Comment: I am using com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0

Comment: please check my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Finally fixed it [thanks to this library](https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/cover"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_arrow_back" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:srcCompat="?android:attr/fingerprintAuthDrawable" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Adding gravity and anchor to recyclerview didn't fix this for me, were you able to get this to work?

Comment: @JCDecary You should not need a `layout_anchor` or `layout_anchorGravity`; if you remove both from your xml it should behave the same way.

Comment: are you also using 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'

Comment: no @EdmundRojas i'm using : 
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'

Answer (score 0):

You have reorder you `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `RecyclerView`. As you may read from documentation CoordinatorLayout is a super-powered FrameLayout. This means that element added second to the layout will be above the element which was added first.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Changing the order didn't fix the issue for me, were you able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is not working because you set the `layout_collapseMode` on your `ImageView` to `none`. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.html#COLLAPSE_MODE_OFF), this will make the view not collapsable:

> The view will act as normal with no collapsing behavior.

You should set this to `layout_collapseMode="parallax"` to get the collapsing behavior. If you want to have the collapsing behavior without the parallax *effect*, then you should set [`layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.html#setParallaxMultiplier(float)) to `0.0` on your `ImageView` as well.

---

Here is the XML I used to test it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:src="@drawable/car"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The problem isn't the image animation unfortunately but instead the recyclerview and image do not coordinate with each other and one overlaps the other, I have not been able to get the basic scrolling behaviour where the recyclerview and image work in unison with one another

Comment: @EdmundRojas Strange, the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` attribute is what coordinates the two. Possibly try my suggestion along with swapping the order as @VolodymyrKhodonovych suggested?

Comment: @EdmundRojas The only other suggestion I have is possibly wrapping your `RecyclerView` in another `View`, such as a `NestedScrollView` (make sure the outer `View` has the `layout_behavior` attribute)? I have not tested a singular `RecyclerView` myself, in every instance of a collapsing toolbar I have the `RecyclerView` is within a `Fragment`.

Comment: I was able to use the nestedscrollview in earlier examples that didn't have a recyclerview, adding the recyclerview it immediately breaks

Comment: @EdmundRojas I just did a simple test with dummy content, I will post the XML I used above. The `RecyclerView` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` are working as expected. Actually it even works with `layout_collapseMode="none"`, which I would argue it *shouldn't*, but oh well. I am running it on API 24 (7.0 Nougat) with `recyclerview-v7:24.2.1` though. Maybe all it will take is an update from `24.0.0`?

Comment: @EdmundRojas I did also notice that if I set the width of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to `match_parent` I could no longer "fling" the `RecyclerView` downward, but otherwise it still works as expected.