# Collapsing Toolbar Layout & Recycler View

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design, android-design-library

I have implemented CollapsingToolbarLayout like appears in the following xml. If the recyclerview has a lot of items, the relative layout with id = info_layout goes up and it's not visible until I scroll down. If the toolbar is gone or invisible, this layout goes down and it's visible partially. What have I done wrong?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout          
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout                
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="10dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBar"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="50dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                    android:padding="8dp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/info_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_500"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"                  
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" 
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"                   
                android:textColor="@color/grey_600"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"/>           

            </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Edited: I followed the suggestion [Android collapsing toolbar with RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838531/android-collapsing-toolbar-with-recyclerview) but when I put the recyclerview before AppBarLayout, it doesn't show the items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android collapsing toolbar with RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838531/android-collapsing-toolbar-with-recyclerview)

Comment: Just guessing (I have not tested) but do you need the android:fitsSystemWindows="true" on the NestedScrollView?

Comment: @ShrenikShah I followed the suggestion Android collapsing toolbar with RecyclerView but when I put the recyclerview before AppBarLayout, it doesn't show the items.